# CEF disable address bar

Tags: chromium-embedded

I am using CEF3 and want to hardcode and disable the address bar of the browser. I am not finding the right place in the code base to do the same. Any pointers would be of great help. 
Either through the C++ or Javascript methods would help.

Thanks,
Ashwin

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [cefclient](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fcef3%2Ftests%2Fcefclient)?  I don't think there's a clean way to turn it off in the standard version of cefclient.

However, in the [brackets-shell fork of cefclient](https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/tree/master/appshell) there's a `#define` you can use to toggle it on/off cleanly.  Just search for references to `SHOW_TOOLBAR_UI` (it's only used in four files).  I'm guessing it wouldn't be too hard to manually apply those diffs back onto a clean copy of cefclient (you probably don't want to take the brackets-shell fork as-is – it's not very generic).

Answer (score 1):

You can build a CEF application using the binary, just like the WIKI does. Please see the github project for a reference  https://github.com/acristoffers/CEF3SimpleSample

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is old but I had the same question and found the solution.

In the `cefclient` example, the address bar is drawn within the `RootWindowGtk::CreateRootWindow` function.

Delete the `gtk_container_add` function call that adds the `GtkToolItem*` corresponding to the address bar and the address bar will be gone.